# Android microphone is not working when it is used by another application in background service

Tags: android, service, android-service, microphone, background-service

I am making an application which uses microphone in background service. so when i activated background service then microphone is not working in other application (ex. google voice search, whatsapp etc.)

I have added following permission for using microphone.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

can anybody tell me why is this happen and how to fix that problem.
plz help
Thank you.

Comment: On many/most Android devices, only one application is allowed to record from the microphone at any given time.

Comment: Thanks michael, can you please tell me that how can I add this permission into my application using code, what I want to do is that I just want to active my microphone while my background service is running else the microphone should be released.

Comment: That sounds like a code issue (i.e. that you have a `MediaRecorder` or `AudioRecord` constantly recording in your service) rather than a permission issue.

Comment: Great solution, you are right at your point. let me check it at my end

Comment: Hello Manish... I am also looking this question answer.. did u found solution??